# Calculate real value of line-height

Tags: javascript

**EDITED**
I have the following HTML Element:

```
<p class="myElement">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

`.myElement` DOES NOT have any `line-height` property in its css. I didn't defined `line-height` (or, assume I defined `line-height` as `normal`/`inherit`/`initial`, any non-numeric value).

I want to calculate the real line-height value (Or - convert the values from above to px/cm/%) with JS. but the only way to get the line-height value is like this:

```
let myElement = document.querySelector(".myElement");
let lineHeight = window.getComputedStyle(myElement, null).getPropertyValue("line-height");
```

and I convert it to number:

```
lineHeight = lineHeight.replace(/[^\d\.]+/g, "");
lineHeight = lineHeight == "" ? 0 : Number(lineHeight);
```

and I get 0, because line-height isn't defined, or it's "normal"/"inherit"/"initial".

How can I calculate the REAL value of `line-height` with JS, and convert these values into px/cm/%?

Answer (score -3):

```js
let myElement = document.querySelector(".myElement");
let lineHeight = myElement.style.lineHeight;
```

It's very simple, just go to styles and get the line-height value which is the style element of the DOM element.

Comment: This only works if the style is *directly* on the HTML element. If it comes from a CSS file, this will not work.

Comment: But why use Javascript if we know the real value? The author probably uses dynamically changing values that he changes from the level of JavaScript and cannot determine the real value for further action on the element or values.

Comment: Well, that's possible, but it's also true that changes in parent class strings can trigger new sets of CSS rules, without the DOM `style` objects changing at all.

Comment: @Pointy, nycaff I have updated my question